# E: Sub-process /sur/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies, 22.04

After running the commands `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in the terminal, my screen suddenly went black.

By rebooting my computer, I had access to a terminal, in which I entered:

- `sudo apt-get update`, which gave the following output:

  [image: output of sudo apt-get update]
- `sudo apt-get upgrade`, which gave the following output:

  [image: output of sudo apt-get upgrade]

So I tried `sudo apt —fix-broken install` as suggested, which gave this:

[image: output of sudo apt —fix-broken install]

I tried running `sudo dpkg —configure -a`, which gave this error:

[image: output of sudo dpkg —configure -a]

and other suggestions, such as `sudo apt autoclean && sudo apt autoremove`, and I tried reinstalling the listed packages but couldn’t.

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu with the command:

```
sudo apt install —reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

which gave this:

[image: output of sudo apt install —reinstall ubuntu-desktop]

and also:

```
sudo apt-get install —no-install-recommends ubuntu-desktop
```

Some solutions suggested to use `remove --purge` to remove the problematic packages, but none are indicated, so now I can only have access to a terminal (Ubuntu 22.04.01 LTS).

Comment: it looks like the update removed some very, very important packages (it's saying a bunch of GUI packages are unnecessary...) Try `sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop` to reinstall all the packages that come with a default Ubuntu system. If you still have issues, post the error messages you get as a result here, in an edit to your question.

Comment: I already tried that but it say the same thing to run apt —fix-broken install

Comment: I retract my previous doubt: There is indeed a reported bug [LP: #1990586](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1990586)...though it seems not to be the actual answer for this particular question.

Comment: Bug fixed about one hour after it was reported. Folks should no longer be autoremoving their system through injudicious use of dist-upgrade.

Comment: @Reeina Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, so a question should not contain the solution. The answer section is where solutions should be. So I moved the solution from the question to a separate answer. I added the answer as a Community Wiki (CW), so that means I won't get any reputation points from possible upvotes. If you want to add the solution yourself as an answer, feel free to add a new one and ping me here by using @ with my username (BeastOfCaerbannog) in a comment so we can delete the CW. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> Thank you so much [user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733) and [Esther](https://askubuntu.com/users/1083397/esther)!
>
> So I did what user535733 said to reinstall `ubuntu-advantage-tools`, which worked, and then reinstalled `ubuntu-desktop` as [Esther suggested](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1431730/resolved-e-sub-process-sur-bin-dpkg-returned-an-error-code-1#comment2493635_1431730).
>
> After that I rebooted my computer and ran:
>
> ```
> sudo apt —fix-broken install
> ```
>
> and:
>
> ```
> sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
> ```

<sup>Answer moved here from OP's question.</sup>